# Project Euler #2 in Java

Tags: java, programming-challenge

Project Euler #2:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

Here is my solution:

```
public class EvenFibonacciFinder {

    private static final double PHI = 1.618033989;
    private static final double _PHI = -(PHI - 1);
    private static final double SQRT_5 = Math.sqrt(5);
    private static final int MAX_NUM = 4_000_000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        double max = MAX_NUM * SQRT_5;
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 3, result = (int) Math.round(2 * SQRT_5); result < max; result = (int) Math.round(Math.pow(PHI, i += 3) - Math.pow(_PHI, i))) {
            sum += result;
        }
        sum = Math.round(sum / SQRT_5);
        System.out.println("Result: " + sum + "\nTime used for calculation in nanoseconds: " + (System.nanoTime() - time));
    }

}
```

Output:

> Result: 4613732
>  Time used for calculation in nanoseconds: 60243

Questions:

- Is this the most efficient way of doing it?
- Is there any "bad code" in the short solution?

Comment: Using the golden ratio to calculate Fibonacci numbers. Slick. +1

Comment: `result = (int) Math.round(Math.pow(PHI, i += 3) - Math.pow(_PHI, i))`. Do you know if java specifies an evaluation order for the increment? I'm not sure which value of `i` is passed to the second `Math.pow`

Comment: @FDinoff It does. Otherwise, my answer will be incorrect (which it isn't).

Comment: @MannyMeng If it works but it isn't clear what's happening, it's often a sign you need to refactor something. Clarity is generally a good thing.

Comment: When going for really big Fibonnaci numbers it's possible to use the fact that fsquared can be calculated. You would have to prepare the calculation so you end up at the exact fib you want, but it can massively reduce the number of calculations necessary.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Is this the most efficient way of doing it?

Sometimes the simplest solution is also the most efficient solution.  I'm not sure why you decided to use `Math.pow` and `PHI` to compute something that can be easily (and more quickly) be computed with simple addition:

```
public class EvenFibonacciFinder {
    private static final int MAX_NUM = 4_000_000;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        int  f1   = 1;
        int  f2   = 2;
        long sum  = 0;

        while (f2 <= MAX_NUM) {
            int f3;
            sum += f2;
            // This skips three ahead in the sequence.
            f3 = f1 + f2;
            f1 = f2 + f3;
            f2 = f1 + f3;
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Result: " + sum +
                "\nTime used for calculation in nanoseconds: " +
                (end - time));
    }
}
```

Output:

> Original code using pow:
>   Result: 4613732
>   Time used for calculation in nanoseconds: 9952
>
> Using addition instead of pow:
>   Result: 4613732
>   Time used for calculation in nanoseconds: 934

(Note: both programs were modified to measure the end time before the `println()`, otherwise some of the string concatentation time was being counted).

Comment: Agreed; the explicit mathematical formula is more elegant, but for a computer, it's more difficult to calculate.

Comment: Wow. I'm a little surprised at the dramatic difference. Goes to show that what's easier for a person isn't always easier for a machine.

Comment: It should be pointed out that the timing mechanism used for measuring this performance is essentially useless... micro-benchmarking on code that has not 'warmed up' leads to misleading diagnostics

Comment: @rolfl Is it the timing mechanism itself or would he want move his code to a method, call the method a few times to "warm-up" then start the timer and use that result? Is this because of memory caching or is there more to it?

Comment: @DoubleDouble a combination of both. It's very hard to benchmark effectively as the JVM has a habit of loading classes and JITing things as it goes. Even with warmup, there is no guarantee that the JVM won't decide to load/compile a whole host of seemingly unrelated stuff randomly. A benchmarking tool like caliper will actually monitor the activity of the underlying JVM to deal with these issues.

Answer (score 11):

With the amount of comments in there, it's really hard to understand. Even for the mathematically superior folk (which I am not), you need to supply more information about what your constants are, why they are needed, and how the function works.

Given the constants you have, and the way it is hard-coded, I would almost go so far as to say your code could be improved by simply:

```
System.out.println("Result: 4613732\nTime used for calculation in nanoseconds: 0");
```

;-0

It makes just as much sense as your complicated formula, and.... it produces the right result, faster.

Comment: Interesting way to look at my code.

Answer (score 4):

Kudos to writing this program. The only thing that I see can be optimised is:

```
    Math.pow(PHI, i += 3) - Math.pow(_PHI, i)
    // PHI^(i+3) - PHI^i = PHI^i*(PHI^3-1) = PHI^i * PHI_CUBE_LESS_1 (Constant). Add comment if used.
```

- Wouldn't `int` suffice rather than using long?

Just add the wiki link in the comment for others to check the mathematical formula :)
Great work!!!

Comment: If `MAX_NUM` is less than 4, the solution is 0, in which is supposed to be: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5... Can you see any even numbers before the fourth number?

Comment: What abt <=4? Could you check that once. The output should be 2.

Comment: 4 will result in 2.

Comment: I must have missed something. Will take that point out. :)

Answer (score 4):

There are a few minor issues with this code. Firstly, the name of the constant `double _PHI` is unclear; it is not obvious that this means `-(PHI - 1)`.

Also, the for loop includes a lot of code in the parentheses. While this is valid code, it is nonstandard and hard to read. Also, you need to scroll to the right to see all of it.

Furthermore, the `i += 3` buried in the for loop is hard to notice, and in general assigning variables in the middle of a method invocation is not a good idea.

This might be refactored into:

```
int i = 3;
int result = (int) Math.round(2 * SQRT_5);
while (result < max) {
     sum += result;
     i += 3;
     result = (int) Math.round(Math.pow(PHI, i) - Math.pow(_PHI, i));
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  It looks like you left an extra `i += 3` in your code.  Presumably you meant the one with `PHI` to be just `i`.

Comment: At first glance, I thought the same thing about `_PHI`, but once you understand that it's the negative inverse of Phi, I think it makes just as much sense as `PHI_NEGATIVE_INVERSE` or `NEGATIVE_INVERSE_PHI`.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you need to compute all Fibonacci numbers anyway, it is certainly faster to do it with a few additions than with computing powers, multiplication AND an addition.
2. The exact formula to compute fibo(i) is `(phi^i - (-1/psi)^i)/sqrt(5)`.  You can sum the `(phi^i - (-1/psi)^i)` and divide by `sqrt(5)` at the end.  But it is not obvious that you can round each `(phi^i - (-1/psi)^i)` and later divide by `sqrt(5)` and round again.  I think it works because of the properties of sqrt(5) and the fact that the rounding alternates between rounding up and rounding down.
3. You can replace (int)Math.round(...) by (int)(0.5+ ... ).  It is much faster (by a factor 20) on my computer, I think the loop fits in the cpu cache.
4. The term `(-1/psi)^i` becomes very small very fast and can be ignored.

Comment: Comment to #2: That is exactly what I did.

Comment: @MannyMeng Yes, I was only questioning the rounding.